# While Loop in Teradata without Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I was wondering if it is possible to use a while loop without a stored procedure?

I want to run a script that will update previous 4 months (201706, 201707, 201708, 201709). I understand that I am capable of adding in ORs but I rather not. Is there any work around?

Original Script:

```
 UPDATE table_name
 SET column = value
 WHERE date IN ('201706','201707','201708','201709')
```

Desired Script:

```
 /*iterating through the month*/
 UPDATE table_name
 SET column = value
 WHERE date = '2017'+month
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data and expected result in formatted text

Comment: @zarruq I do not think it is needed. My question is just if I am able to iterate through update statements. However, I have added desired script for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is no.  It won't work outside a stored procedure.  Even in stored procedures, loops are generally the last resort for just about anything in Teradata.  Teradata is designed to be massively parallel.  Loops by their very nature are sequential and therefore not good for performance in Teradata.  Instead, you should try to do it in a set based way.  For example, your months and values go into a table.  Then you do an update from that table so that all the values in "table_name" are updated in a single query.

Comment: Alternativey, you could just do multiple update statements with no loop

Comment: That is unfortunate, I am unable to query the original script due to spool space issues. I guess I'll have to due it 1 by 1. Thanks @DavidCram

Comment: You could script this in a language outside of teradata if you lack access to create a proc in your system. Since your actual code isn't here, I can only guess, but perhaps switch to using volatile tables to hold your intermediate result sets that are causing you the spool issues. It will give you more control than breaking it up into chunks like this.

Comment: *I am unable to query the original script due to spool space issues* A single-table Update will not use spool unless you're modifying a Primary Index column.